# Identify “Start” and “End” date of a trip in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to get how many times a pack has been used in any given month, Each time the pack is activated it can be used for 7 days.

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

I have tried Lag and lead along with nesting the query.

Comment: Please include the sample input/output data directly in your question as _text_, then delete the image links.  External links can, and often do, break over time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's not letting me add it as a text. every time I copy-paste my data it says add as an image.

Comment: You need a recursive CTE in order to solve this.  You should really be keeping track of when packs are activated, not just when they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

```
select
  max([Date]) as Month_END,
  Line_Number,
  Pack_Code,
  Product_Code,
  count(1) as [Number Of Packs]
from
  Table
group by
  datepart(mm, [Date]),
  Line_Number,
  Pack_Code,
  Product_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the date to year month using the below syntax and then apply a group by on the required columns to get the count of the pack_code

```
to_char(to_Date(LOADED_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYYMM') year_month
```

Sample query:

```
select a.year_month,a.line_number,a.pack_code,a.product_code,count(a.pack_code)
select to_char(to_Date(LOADED_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYYMM') year_month,line_number,pack_code,product_code,count(pack_code)
from <table_name> ) a 
group by a.year_month,a.line_number,a.pack_code,a.product_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issue with my laptop. Before i complete my answer, it has posted my response :).
My previous answer will give you the total number of times in a month a pack has been used under count variable. You can then divide the aggregated value by 7 to identify the number of active packs. Hope it helps